# Finding a specific link from a site

Tags: html, web, xidel

I'm trying to find a specific link from a web page using windows command line and tools. I think Xidel can do what I want to do.
In the page, the link is used like this:

```
file: 'http://link.link/index.txt'
```

Note: there's only one line like this. Now if I can set something like

> file: '{%link}'

then I'll be able to extract the link. Also if I want to change the word index.txt to something like root.txt and then use aria2 to download the link as http://link.link/root.txt , what do I need to do?

(I don't have any experience with any of these tools/command like scripts, I just wanted to make something that does this (some alternatives are already available but I want to do it myself) and this only. So I did search for it and have an idea on how can I do it but extrating the exact url seems to be the hardest part since I couldn't find anything that might help me in xidel's docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xidel is meant to extract data from HTML/XML/json files, but it can also extract from CSV's and TXT if you know how to use the $raw variable and xidel/xquery functions, like extract(), tokenize() and replace().

Post the URL or the source (or part thereof) of the webpage and I'll see how I can help you.